# I'm unable to install Gnome in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, gnome, package-management, dpkg

This is what comes up when I try to install Gnome via Terminal:

```
ansh@Ansh-HP-Notebook:~$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for ansh:

E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

ansh@Ansh-HP-Notebook:~$ sudo apt install ubuntu-gnome-desktop

E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Comment: Is "software updater" open in the taskbar? I had that problem yesterday actually. If all else fails, just reboot.

Answer (score -1):

### This should be used as last resort. If you use this carelessly, you can end up with a broken system

remove the `lock` :

```
sudo rm  /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

configure `dpkg` :

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

update your apt-get :

`sudo apt-get update --fix-missing`

Comment: That is a very dangerous option, and should only be used as a last resort.

Comment: should i remove the answer ?

Comment: No, because it is a valid last resort.  I put in a bold warning at the top for you.